# C#'s CA1900 warning - aligning fields on 4-byte boundaries

Tags: c#, memory-alignment, analyzer

When running analyzer, I get this:

Warning CA1900  Structure 'PageHeader' contains the following non-portable fields: 'PageHeader.TicksInPage'

I do have [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)] on, and the TicksInPage is defined as:

```
    [FieldOffset(14)]
    public int TicksInPage;
```

So I can see how there is the not-on-bounds problem. My question is - this code has been running for a while both in 32- and 64-bit Windows, with no problems. This is a desktop application, not a server application. Should I care at all about this warning?

Answer (score 0):

It's saying your code is platform specific and could potentially behave differently depending on whether your code is on a 32 bit or 64 bit OS, or another platform. And you probably have Platform target set to "Any CPU" on the project Build configuration.

Comment: Well, I am not sure - if the target is set to "Any CPU" - does that mean the application is supposed to be able to run on Itanium as well?

Comment: Judging by the documentation, the rule appears to be explicitly aimed at Itanium (IA-64).

Comment: That's what I thought - so if the application is targeted at laptop/desktop users, not servers, I can safely ignore that warning, I guess?